# Load Pivot Table to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, pivot-table

I would like to ask a question. I want to load one pivot table from Jupyter Notebook (Python) to BigQuery.
Below is my pivot table in Jupyter:
[image]

And here is the output in Bigquery
[image]

I'm using this code to load to BQ:

```
dfnew.to_gbq(destination_table='table.DLV',project_id='projectA',if_exists='append')
```

I want the pivot table in BigQuery to be the same as in Jupyter but it didn't load the Email and Name column there.

Is it possible to load the pivot table in BigQuery? Can anyone help me? Please!

Comment: Did you try to `reset_index` before exporting?

Comment: @Cylldby can2. but we can display exactly like the table in python?

Comment: if I understand correctly your question the columns `Email` and `Name` (the *index* of the dataframe) are not loaded in BQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```py
(dfnew
 .reset_index()
.to_gbq(destination_table='table.DLV',project_id='projectA',if_exists='append')
)
```

According to the to_gbq [doc](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing.html#inferring-the-table-schema):

> The to_gbq() method infers the BigQuery table schema based on the dtypes of the uploaded DataFrame.

but if you print dfnew.dtypes, you will not see `Email` and `Name`, because they're in the index.
That's why you need to `reset_index`.